# Как вывести среднее арифметическое?

Tags: c, массивы

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
int main() 
{
    
    int n, sum = 0, i, count=0;
    printf("n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
 
    int arr[n];
 
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d elem: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        sum += arr[i];
    }
 
    int average = sum/n;
    printf("arithmetic mean: \n",average);
    printf("Elements less than average: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (arr[i]<average){
            ++count;
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вы и не просите вывести :) Написали бы хотя бы

```
printf("arithmetic mean: %d\n",average);
```

Но! деление нацело для среднего даст не совсем точный (совсем не точный) результат, так что я бы делал так:

```
double average = (double)sum/n;
printf("arithmetic mean: %lf\n",average);
```